# IE8 Session Issue

Tags: session, internet-explorer-8, bind

I am not sure how to put it as it sounds weird, but IE8 seems to be dropping sessions. I am talking about sessions in the server, HTTP sessions.

I know that a browser does not as such have to do anything with the HTTP session in the application server, but it seems when I request the server to fetch something I previously stored in the session, it returns a "null".

I go...

```
session.setAttribute(YGConstants.SEARCH_STRING, searchString);
```

and then I say

```
session.getAttribute(YGConstants.SEARCH_STRING);
```

I get a "null".

Is this a known issue? Am I missing something specific to IE8 or have I not "Googled" enough?

When I use any of the Firefox, Chrome, IE6, IE7 and Opera browsers it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

*I know that a browser does not as such have to do anything with the HTTP session in the Application server*

Sure it does: it sends the cookie to the server that the server uses to keep track of the server-side session state.

Use Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) to monitor your requests and ensure that the session cookie is being reliably sent.

Comment: Thanks Eric, 'I fiddled with Fiddler2', its an amazing tool for IE, but then I am still at the same page...the session issue is still not resolved...

Comment: ...And did you look to see if the session cookie is getting set.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you this late...
The Session cookie gets set..but somehow I notice that the session id changes during a session...Something like I have a session id 'X' when the application started...and while I was searching for images in the application...the session id sent in the search request CHANGED and as the application checks for a valid user...I am redirected back to the login page..

Comment: And did you then look at which request was sent to the server that caused the server to send a Set-Cookie header which changed the session ID?

Answer (score 0):

In case it has something to do with your case, we had the same problem, but not on all servers. We eventually found that the problems were only when on the server whose name had an underscore ("_") character in it. Removing the underscore from the domain name solved the problem.